# How to implement payment functionality in android app

Tags: android

I m wrkng on a passenger app. A passenger is able to book a vehicle through this app and he can also pays his fair through app. I want that the passenger pays the money by his credit card onL9 through this app but I nvr worked before with any kind of payment functionality. Is there any one who helped Me for this? just tell Me any link, any tutorial, any kind of APi used for payments, or any other example link etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1.You can integrate `PayPal`, and accept the payments through `Paypal`. You can integrate `Paypal` in your app using [`ExpressCheckoutSDK`](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECOnMobileDevices). You will though have to create a `Paypal` seller account, and also integrate `Paypal` on your server to check that the payments have been done, etc.

2.You can use [`Google In-App Billing`](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) to make the payments through `PlayStore`.

Comment: Do u have any tutorial or example link, which help me to implement that how to use with Paypal?